# How to delete a whole word from a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

My program only deletes the first word "she" but the rest isn't affected. How can I delete it?

```cpp
int main()
{
    string mess = "she realizes she is her only hope and she stopped expecting help from others.";
    string word_to_delete = "she";

    int mess_len = (int)mess.length();
    int word_len = (int)word_to_delete.length();
        
    for(int i = 0; i < mess_len; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < word_len; k++)
        {
            if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[i])
            {
                mess[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << mess;
}
```

Comment: I think the best 2 solutions are created by 2 users "rawrex" and "akash". Theirs are short, clear, precise, fast, and efficient. Both work well as I have tested.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider looking toward the following approach instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mess = "she realizes she is her only hope and she stopped expecting help from others.";
    string word_to_delete = "she";

    auto iter = mess.find(word_to_delete);
    // Iterate through the whole string searching for desired substrings
    while (iter != string::npos) {
        // Erase "she" plus a space after it (may require more fine tuning)
        mess.erase(iter, word_to_delete.length() + 1);
        // Advance further, look for "she" starting from iter
        iter = mess.find(word_to_delete, iter);
    }
    cout << mess << '\n';
}
```

Here, we use [string's method](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) `find` to look for a desired substring, then we use `erase` [method](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) to delete the `word_to_delete` (plus a space) from the `mess`.

Example output:

```
realizes is her only hope and stopped expecting help from others.
```

Comment: This is a great solution : efficient, fast, clear and standardized.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you can use regular expression also to replace that word with something. Simple code snippet below for reference.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string mess = "she realizes she is her only hope and she stopped expecting help from others.";
string word_to_delete = "she";
mess = std::regex_replace(mess, regex(word_to_delete), "");
cout<<"\nUpdated mess: "<<mess;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very fast and efficient solution too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There was some misunderstanding or wrong logic by you inside for loop. Also you have to check all char before starting to replace them.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mess = "she realizes she is her only hope and she stopped expecting help from others.";
    // getline(cin, mess);
    string word_to_delete = "she";
    int mess_len = (int)mess.length();
    int word_len = (int)word_to_delete.length();
    int flag=-1;

    for(int i = 0; i < mess_len; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < word_len; k++)
        {
            if(mess[i+k] == word_to_delete[k])
            {
                flag=i;
            }
            else{
                flag=-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag!=-1){
            mess.erase(flag, word_len);
        }
    }
    cout << mess;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried providing some code examples below, along with some explanations, to show I fixed it.

The issues are in your nested loop:

```
...

for(int k = 0; k < word_len; k++)
{
    if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[i])
    {
        mess[i] = 0;
    }
}

...
```

1.**Incorrect Index to word_to_delete[]**

Remember that this nested loop iterates through a subsection of the array 'mess', and iterates completely through the string "she". "she" is stored in word_to_delete. Notice: you use the index 'i' (defined in the outer loop) to index to word_to_delete.

```
if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[i])
```

'i' will go through the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... until the final index of 'mess'. But, word_to_delete has only 3 elements! Instead, use the index 'k' that you've already defined in the nested loop:

```
if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[k])
```

2. **Entire Word-To-Delete is not matched**

I tested and ran your program after the fix I just mentioned, here was the new output:

> aa raliz  i r only op and  toppd xpcting lp from otr.

As you can see, your program only deletes all the characters in 'mess' that's also in 'word_to_delete'!

This is because in this step:

```
if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[i])
{
    mess[i] = 0;
}
```

you are checking the characters 1-by-1, and then changing them as soon as the characters match. You must check that ALL characters in word_to_delete matches a subsection of mess[], before changing it to 0.

1 solution is to *declare a new int variable 'count'* (initialized to 0) before the nested loop. Then, change the line:

```
 mess[i] = 0;
```

to:

```
count += 1;
```

Which counts up 1 for each character match that word_to_delete makes.

Remember: you only want to delete a subsection of 'mess' if each character matches 'she'. So, *after the nested loop*, check the variable 'count' to see how many matches there were.

If *count equals the length of word_to_delete*, then the string "she" has been found. Else, if there were not enough matches, the subsection is not equal to "she".

This will look something like:

```
if(count==word_len)
{
    // iterate over subsection again and delete all characters,
    // this may require an additional for-loop
}
```

3. **No Offset in Nested Loop**

The final fix is a simple one:

In your nested loop, you are not 'offsetting i'.

Here:

```
for(int k = 0; k < word_len; k++)
{
    // you are looping 'k' times, but you are always checking 'i'!
    if(mess[i] == word_to_delete[k])
    {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

notice that, in the if block, you are using the same value 'i'. But, 'i' does not change when you iterate through values of 'k' = 0, 1, 2.

Instead, a common programming pattern is to use 'i' as your base value, and then the values of k to offset from it.

Remember: when we iterate through 'mess', we want to check a subsection. In your example, we want to check a character, and then the next 2 characters. So, at mess[4], we also want to see mess[5], mess[6]. At mess[27], we also check mess[28], mess[29].

We can do this by changing your nested loop again to:

```
for(int k = 0; k < word_len; k++)
{
    // now, since k = 0,1,2 in this loop,
    // if i = 7, then this loop will go through:
    // mess[7], mess[8], mess[9]
    if(mess[i+k] == word_to_delete[k])
    {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

We don't need to change the index for word_to_delete, because k only goes through 0,1,2, which are already the correct indices for word_to_delete. This will match every subsection of mess[] against word_to_delete[].

After implementing these changes, the final output seems correct:

> realizes  is her only hope and  stopped expecting help from others.

Note: I've noticed a potential bug due to how the character is deleted, but it's better for you to understand the other problems in your code first.